# Android Studio keep asking for signing configuration though I already have for the release build APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-signing

I have in my build.gradle:

```
android {
   signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            try {
                storeFile file("mykey.keystore")
                storePassword "store_password"
                keyAlias "myapp"
                keyPassword "key_passowrd"
               )
            }
            catch (ignored) {
                throw new InvalidUserDataException("Something wrong")
            }
        }
    }

   buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            versionNameSuffix '-RELEASE'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}
```

In build variant, I choose "release". Then, I run my app on connected device, however, Android Studio keep popping up dialog saying:

[image]

But I do have signing configuration...

In build output, I don't see that app-release.apk either :

[image]

Why I get the error then? My Android Studio version is 3.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to provide a link to your `signingConfigs`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ...
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify which signing config should be used for build type

`debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
      }`

Also signing config names should not (but may!) match build type names (eg you may define `alpha` and `beta` signing configs and use them as

`debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.alpha
      }`

By default gradle (android plugin) provides 'system' debug signing config so you may just skip it but it will be available (currently your build script overrides 'system' signing config